# What is the correct way to close a file opened inside object initialization?

Tags: python

I would like to have a class that gets passed either a string or an already opened file during initialization. If it gets a string, it opens the file.

```py
from typing import IO

class Parser:
  def __init__(self, fin: str|IO[str]) -> None:
    if isinstance(fin, str):
      self.fin = open(fin, 'r')
    else:
      if not fin.readable():
        raise ValueError("Input file must be readable.")
      else:
        self.fin = fin
```

My question is, what is the correct way to close the file if it gets opened. I imagined it could be closed in the `__del__` method, but after reading up on it, it seems to be the consensus that using `__del__` is not a great idea. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what about a `def close` function inside the `class`, something like `self.fin.close()`

Comment: What is the class going to be used for? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832); give the context. For example, if it's used similarly to `json.load()`, the best option is probably not opening the file inside the class in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide a separate class method to deal with opening and closing the file using a context manager.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


class Parser:
    def __init__(self, fh: IO[str]) -> None:
        if not fh.readable():
            raise ValueError(...)
        self.fh = fh

    # Typing-hinting is out of scope for this question, so I'm
    # just using the Python-3.11-style Self hint for simplicity.
    @classmethod
    @contextmanager
    def from_filename(cls: Self, name: str) -> Self:
        with open(name) as fh:
            yield Parser(fh)
```

Now you can use either

```
with open("some_file.txt") as fh:
    p = Parser(fh)
    ...
```

or

```
with Parser.from_filename("some_file.txt") as p:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `__del__` should ***NOT*** be used for this purpose, since it is highly unpredictable when it is called.

Also, best is to avoid side-effects (such as opening files) in `__init__`, so I really like the [solution by chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407333/10669875). When possible, that's the method I would choose.

Just to add an alternative: you could also implement a `close` method and then use [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) like this:

```py
import contextlib

class Parser:

    # your __init__ here

    def close(self):
        self.fin.close()


parser = Parser('test.txt')
with contextlib.closing(parser):
    # do something with the object here
    # the file will be automatically closed afterwards
```

Even better, you could make the class a context manager itself like below, which is a bit similar to the answer of chepner. (You could even combine a number of these methods, depending on your needs).

```py
class Parser:

    # your __init__ here

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.fin.close()


with Parser('test.txt') as parser:
    # do some stuff here...
```